# How to fix layout issue with Columns and Image Alignments?

Tags: wordpress-theming, blogs, wordpress-gutenberg

Recently blog columns and images are not aligning correctly on my websites blog. The rest of my site is not effectuated by the issue. The layout looks correct in the blog preview but when you go to the live post the layout is completely broken.

Source URL : 
https://methodprinting.com/blog/2019/04/22/from-design-to-print/

I have tried to disable all plugins and that did not help. I've removed the minified CSS and HTML but no luck there. I also tried to switch from child theme to primary theme and it was still broken.

Comment: It is clearly a theme css issue. Without providing more information on what is wrong on your page ( others don't see it because we don't know what is right), it is hard to help. Try the inspector. Try another theme. See if problem persists or give us more to work with.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond. I did try switching the theme but the current theme utilizes WPBakery Page Builder so when I switch to test on a new theme, such as Twenty Nineteen, the site is overall broken because WPBakery is compatible with it. I will try to find the problem again with inspector. I did not have luck the first time. Honestly it wasn't a problem until recently and nothing really updated. I think I did rebuild the CSS Minify file recently perhaps I try to fix the issue through there. Thanks again for trying to help.

Comment: show your thanks also with voting comments or answers up.

Comment: I don't have the option to vote comments. Does it require a specific rep lvl?